# Why is this SQL (join) query slow when joining on a column that uses select max?

Tags: sql, derby

I'm using Apache Derby 10.8 if it makes a difference.

I have a very simple database with a table full of items and a table full of bids on those items.  I want to select every item with the highest bid for that item joined to it.  The following is my first try at it and the performance is awful:

```sql
select
    item.id as item_id,
    item.name as item_name,
    item.retail_value as item_retail_value,
    item.vendor as item_vendor,
    bid.bid_amount as bid_amount,
    bid.bidder_name as bid_bidder_name,
    bid.bidder_phone as bid_bidder_phone,
    bid.operator_name as bid_operator_name
from item
    left outer join bid on bid.item_id = item.id and
    bid.bid_amount = (select max(bid.bid_amount) from bid where bid.item_id = item.id and bid.status = 'OK')
```

I created a set of test data that uses 282 items with 200 bids for each item (56400 bids total).  The above query takes around 30-40 seconds to run.  If I select every item and manually loop through the items selecting high bids for each, it takes less than a second.

I've tried indexing the `bid.bid_amount` and `bid.status` columns, but it didn't do anything noticeable.  SQL isn't my strongest area, so if anyone is willing to explain **why** that query is so slow I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query's slow because you're doing what's called a correlated subquery--it's running that `max` for each row.

Try something like this:

```
select
    item.id as item_id,
    item.name as item_name,
    item.retail_value as item_retail_value,
    item.vendor as item_vendor,
    bid.bid_amount as bid_amount,
    bid.bidder_name as bid_bidder_name,
    bid.bidder_phone as bid_bidder_phone,
    bid.operator_name as bid_operator_name
from 
    item
    left outer join (
        select 
            item_id, 
            MAX(bid_amount) maxamount 
        from 
            bid 
        where 
            status = 'OK' 
        group by 
            item_id
    ) b1 on
        item.id = b1.item_id
    left outer join bid on
        bid.item_id = item.id
        and bid.bid_amount = b1.maxamount
```

This subquery is only run once, and it will go much faster.

Comment: +1 : I'd also recommend an INDEX on `status, item_id, bid_amount` to make the sub-query nippier.  *(Or possibly `item_id, status, bid_amount` as that is also friendly to the LEFT JOIN.)*

Comment: I just realized Eric's and my answers are practically identical. Voted one up for Eric!

Comment: That gets it down to about half a second without any extra indexes.  Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You created a synchronized (or correlated) subquery. The subquery is executed for every row of the outer table (item).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your nested subquery is running on each and every step of the JOIN operation. No wonder query performance is poor, the CPU and disk are probably hard at work! Assuming you are trying to get the maximum OK'd bid for every item in the items table, you might want to try this query:

```
SELECT I.id AS item_id,
       I.name AS item_name,
       I.retail_value AS item_retail_value,
       I.vendor AS item_vendor,
       B.bid_amount AS bid_amount,
       B.bidder_name AS bid_bidder_name,
       B.bidder_phone AS bid_bidder_phone,
       B.operator_name AS bid_operator_name
FROM item AS I
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT item_id, MAX(bid_amount) AS bid_amount
                      FROM bid
                      WHERE STATUS = 'OK'
                      GROUP BY item_id) AS _TEMP ON _TEMP.item_id = B.item_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN bid AS B ON B.item_id = _TEMP.item_id AND B.bid_amount = _TEMP.bid_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also improve the performance of the query by applying indexing on bid.item_id since the sub query is picking records on the basis of item_id.